# Section not scaling within another div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I need the .hero-overlay (Wheat beer glass section) container to be responsive when scaled down and to stay contained within the hero-image (960x300 image). Right now, when the browser is narrowed, the div spills over the hero-image.

On small devices, such as mobile phones (320px and smaller), I plan on hiding the hero overlay. On medium to desktop devices, I need the image and overlay to scale proportionally.

http://jsfiddle.net/heymila/kWv7R/

```
<section class="header-hero">
    <div class="hero-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/960x300"/></div>
        <div class="hero-overlay span5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                    <p class="lead">Wheat beer glass</p>
                    <p>Wheat beer glass, anaerobic malt extract tulip glass. hops aau tulip glass, yeast heat exchanger hops bottle conditioning?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end hero-overlay -->
</section>
```

Comment: how you want to make it visible in smaller width devices? solution depends on that requirement only.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you needed. I just added width 100%; for the .hero-overlay and set fixed height to 300px for the image and .hero-overlay. seems to be working

```
    .hero-overlay { 
        background:#000;
        opacity:0.5; 
        color:#FFF; 
        padding:20px; 
        position:relative; 
        height:300px; 
        width: 100%;
        float:right;
}

  .hero-image img {
      max-width:100%;
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      height:300px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue you're seeing is that when the page is re-sized the hero image scales down proportionally since it's set to `max-width:100%;`. So it's not the `hero-overlay` that is spilling over, it's the `.hero-image` that is shrinking.

Now as for your solution, this could be handled several ways depending on how you wanted to approach the problem, and what trade-offs you're willing to make, but this solution may work for you:

HTML:

```
<div class="hero-image"></div> //remove the image from here
```

CSS:

```
.hero-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/960x300') no-repeat; // make it a background image here
    background-position: center;  
}
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kWv7R/5/)**

The benefit of doing it this way is you get your image at full height regardless of screen size, and it won't squish the image as the screen gets smaller. The only drawback is that the outer edges get cut off as the page is sized down (if you're okay with that).